# Directory not read

Tags: linux, directory, inode, debian-10

I have a problem with a user's folder.
`ls -la` shows the permissions as `????` instead of drwx.

I tried with

> sudo chmod ug+rw -R /path/folder

to reassign the value but it doesn't change.
How can i make the folder writable by the group?
The user is able to read and write, but the group fails.

screenshot:
[image: wrong inode screenshot]

output text:

```
gra@xxx:~$ ls -la /home/EnGi/D/
ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/EnGi/D/BKDiscoDT30': Permesso negato
ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/EnGi/D/..': Permesso negato
ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/EnGi/D/.': Permesso negato
totale 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? BKDiscoDT30
gra@xxxx:~$ sudo chmod ugo+r -R /home/EnGi/D
[sudo] password di gra: 
gra@xxxx:~$ ls -la /home/EnGi/D/
ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/EnGi/D/BKDiscoDT30': Permesso negato
ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/EnGi/D/..': Permesso negato
ls: impossibile accedere a '/home/EnGi/D/.': Permesso negato
totale 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? BKDiscoDT30
gra@xxx:~$
```

Comment: What is the result of `umask`?

Comment: Hello, welcome to serverfault. Please [do not post text as screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349491/should-i-replace-terminal-screenshots-by-plain-text) - makes it hard to read for everyone, impossible to read for blind users and search engines. I took the liberty of editing it for you.

Comment: `gra@xxxx:~$ sudo stat /home/EnGi/D 
  File: /home/EnGi/D
  Dim.: 4096       Blocchi: 8          Blocco di IO: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 9440007     Coll.: 3
Accesso: (0744/drwxr--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/    EnGi)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Accesso  : 2021-10-07 14:38:23.187827428 +0200
Modifica : 2021-06-03 20:02:03.357812958 +0200
Cambio   : 2021-10-07 14:38:17.067827441 +0200
Creazione: -
`

Comment: `gra@xxxx:~$ umask -S 
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
`